# Permission denied to access property 'filepicker_comm_iframe'

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jquery-events, filepicker

Currently facing an issue with Filepicker's iframe in my application... my tools:

- Framework: Rails 4 (including turbolinks)
- API: Filepicker.io (JS)
- File type: Coffeescript

My sample code:

```
ready = ->
filepicker_api_key = $js_data.data('filepickerApiKey')
unprocessed_path = $js_data.data('unprocessedPath')
filepicker.setKey(filepicker_api_key)
  $('#image-upload').click (e) ->

    picker_options =
    services: ['COMPUTER']
    mimetypes: ['image/*']

    store_options =
    location: 's3'
    path: unprocessed_path
    access: 'public'

    filepicker.pickAndStore picker_options, store_options ->
      console.log 'foobar'
      # alot of code comes here.. which works whenever I refresh the page

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

It stops once I try uploading something. My logs show this error:

> Error: Permission denied to access property
> 'filepicker_comm_iframe'

and doesn't show my `'foobar'` log

But when I refresh the page, I receive no error, and the file
uploads accordingly. I am trying to avoid the flaw of having to
refresh the page in order to upload successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Since with turbolinks the body is reloaded, I suggest to move in layout file this code:

```
<%= filepicker_js_include_tag %>
```

from `<head>` to `<body>`.

It should work fine then (in Rails 4, without installing 'jquery-turbolinks' gem).
In the future we will work on the general solution, independent on where this tag was placed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue, by adding `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'` to my Gemfile (thus running bundle), and including `//= jquery.turbolinks` to my application.js.

So far this has been the only valuable work around that I've come across. For this specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

After loaded, filepicker js add 2 iframes to body. When you use turbolinks to change page, they are gone. So you need to add them again by your self:

```
    if $("#filepicker_comm_iframe").length == 0
      $("body").append '<iframe name="filepicker_comm_iframe" id="filepicker_comm_iframe" src="https://dialog.filepicker.io/dialog/comm_iframe/" style="display: none;"></iframe>'
    if $("#fpapi_comm_iframe").length == 0
      $("body").append '<iframe name="fpapi_comm_iframe" id="fpapi_comm_iframe" src="https://www.filepicker.io/dialog/comm_iframe/" style="display: none;"></iframe>'
```